# Some questions about UIViews and UITextFields

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, cocos2d-iphone, uitextfield

1. Can UITextFields only be added to UIViews?

   1a. If they cant, how do you add UITextFields to CCSprites?

   1b. If they cant, how do I make my own UIView programmatically not using the Interface Builder? (links welcome)
2. I have a scene, how do I display a custom UIView from it?

Answer (score 0):

UITextField is UIView subclass and can be added to all UIView classes and subclasses. I don't know what is CCSprites class; if this class have a method like `-(void)addView:(UIView*)view;` then you can use this method.

For creating UIView programmaticaly use this code:

```
UIView *_topHolderView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100)] autorelease];
_topHolderView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self addSubview:_topHolderView]; 
//[self.view addSubview:_topHolderView];
```

Comment: Do you know how to display a UIView from a CCScene?

Comment: No, i don't know. I think you should use Cocos2D classes for your aims if you using Cocos2d framework.

Comment: Ohh.. I think that's probably why I'm having so many problems. Can you not mix frameworks? And do you know of anything similar to a TextField in the Cocos2D framework?

Comment: Check this link [UIView Cocos2d wrapper](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/6889)